# пишу тему на wordpress, возникли сложности с работой файла single.php

Tags: php, wordpress

Пишу тему на wordpress  с нуля, установил wordpress, создал тему и в этой папке создал следующие файлы:

```
index.php
style.css   // заполнено согласно инструкции
screenshot.png
header.php
footer.php
```

header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
      crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp"
      crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Font-awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/style/mystyle.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/style.css"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <title><?php wp_title (" "); ?> | <?php if (wp_title (" ", false)) { echo " | "; } ?><?php bloginfo ("name"); ?></title>

  <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- All content on the page -->
<div id="cont">
```

index.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="content">
<?php if (have_posts ()) : ?>
  <?php while (have_posts ()) : the_post (); ?>

    <!-- article's block -->
    <div class="container color_green">
            <div class=«title»>
                <h1>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php the_title (); ?>
                    </a>
                    <span>
                        <i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <?php comments_popup_link('0', '1', '%'); ?>
                    </span>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <img src="http://vremena-goda.su/photo/1-0/157_image_154.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                    <h3><?php the_content (__ ('Читать полностью'));?></h3>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        Читать полностью
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr>
        <div class="date">
            <?php the_time ('F dS, Y') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 30px"></div>
    <!-- end of article's block -->

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p><?php _e ('Такая страница не существует'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

single.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="content">
<?php if (have_posts ()) : ?>
  <?php while (have_posts ()) : the_post (); ?>
    <div class="container">
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <h3><?php the_content(); ?></h3>
    </div> 
  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

footer.php:

```
  <!--  FOOTER   -->
    <h1>FOOTER</h1>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

ВСЕ остальные файлы пустые.
В общем, выводит все статьи (index.php), а при переходе по ссылке на одну статью (single.php) все равно выводит ВСЕ статьи!НО! в адресной строке прописан адрес ЭТОЙ статьи, на которую перешел! Я делаю это по видео с ютуба ([https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jlEHHwSGepg&index=4&list=PLzi5JvpYf_hh6NaL1o0aYIpEdICG7P0gK)...код](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jlEHHwSGepg&index=4&list=PLzi5JvpYf_hh6NaL1o0aYIpEdICG7P0gK)...%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4) писал вместе с ним...там у него все работает почему-то...Но мне кажется, что загвоздка в файле single.php в строке:

```
<?php if (have_posts ()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts ()) : the_post (); ?>
```

потому, что здесь тоже запускается цикл вывода статей и они выводятся ВСЕ, а не конкретная...там получается должно быть что-то вроде индекса и цикл должен просто перебирать статьи в поиске нужной? Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться

Comment: Файлы выглядят правильными. Цикл в single.php должен быть. WordPress сам делает запрос WP_Query, в который попадает ровно один пост, этот пост и выводится циклом в single.php. У меня есть голая тема для экспериментов, добавил сейчас в неё single.php - все ок, выводится один пост. Где-то у вас, похоже, сайт не соответствует тому коду, что вы поместили в вопросе.

Comment: @KAGG Design , хммм....очень странно.....

Comment: А уберите single.php, что будет? )

Comment: @KAGG Design, убрал, ничего НЕ поменялось...получается, что и когда он был проект просто НЕ заглядывал в этот файл???права у меня стоят везде 777 на проекте (в учебных целях, еще дошел до того, чтоб разобраться что скрывать а что нет)

Comment: Когда single.php нет, WordPress сам реализует ее функционал. И у меня без single.php выводит ровно 1 пост, как положено. Права доступа к файлам роли не играют, лишь бы php мог выполнить эти файлы. Посты в базе, так что вывод 1 или все от прав на файлы не зависит. У вас голый WordPress или есть еще плагины?

Comment: @KAGG Design , голый wordpress без плагинов, подключил только библиотеки bootstrap, fa, jquery по ссылкам CDN, ну Вы видели в коде. а так больше ничего в проекте нет

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62513/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-).

Comment: В общем, за исключением одной небольшой ошибки в коде Index.php, все правильно. У меня на тестовом сайте работает. Очевидно, что автор вопроса где-то допустил ошибку в другом месте. Голосую за закрытие вопроса, поскольку ошибку воспроизвести не удается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в скаченном архиве wordpress. Я скачал проект заново :

```
https://wordpress.org/download/
```

и мой код темы заработал. Спасибо большое за помощь в решении данной проблемы. Кто столкнется с чем-то подобным - используйте данную ссылку на скачку архива wordpress. Код самописной темы рабочий.